# How to split bytes from NSData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, byte, nsdata

So.. I have encrypted data from server that need to be decrypted so that I can get the full response JSON. The thing is I need to split the first 16 bytes of data to get the IV for decryption and the rest of the bytes is the encrypted data. I tried below method:

```
NSData *wholeData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:@"IYSaYh92saFT5t/ueQQtlTaFT1oW33FXPLDUsRMATBLUrY/6Z1VGK1KFmyeRwHpbi85T7ZNzDQAl5v8cu60DcJLwVQDI6KdwbmCq0+L62IM7Ixw60+G8gTkm+6+MLtyE" options:0];

NSData *d1 = [wholeData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 16)];
NSData *d2 = [wholeData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(17, wholeData.length)];

NSData *enc = d2;
NSData *key = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:@"alskd81039aisdf/tusd8341iasldkjfY=" options:0];
NSData *enciv = d1;

NSData *decrypted = [FBEncryptorAES decryptData:enc key:key iv:enciv];
```

Then I got below error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteData subdataWithRange:]: range {17, 96} exceeds data length 96'

How can I fix my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSData *d2 = [wholeData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(17, wholeData.length - 17)];
```

Comment: What a same, I forgot to reduce the whole amount. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I'm guessing 17 here represents bytes?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 NSData* blob;
    NSUInteger length = [blob length];
    NSUInteger chunkSize = 100 * 1024;
    NSUInteger offset = 0;
    do {
        NSUInteger thisChunkSize = length - offset > chunkSize ? chunkSize : length - offset;
        NSData* chunk = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:(char *)[blob bytes] + offset
                                             length:thisChunkSize
                                       freeWhenDone:NO];
        offset += thisChunkSize;
        // do something with chunk
    } while (offset < length);
```